# Use MVT to prove that $1-\cos x<x^2$ for $x\neq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Use MVT to prove that $1-\cos x<x^2$, $x\neq 0$

$$1-\cos x<x^2\implies 1<x^2+\cos x$$
Let $f(x)=x^2+\cos x$,

Notice that $f(-x)=(-x)^2+\cos(-x)=x^2+\cos(x)=f(x) \implies f$ is symmetric about the y-axis.
It suffices to show that $x^2+\cos x>1$ for $x>0$ due to this symmetry.

$x>0 \implies (0,x)$

Since $x^2$ and $\cos x$ are differentiable (and thus continuous) $\forall x\in \mathbb R$, MVT yields that in $(0,x)$, $\exists c \in (0,x)$ such that
$$\frac{(x^2+\cos x)-(0^2-\cos 0)}{x-0}=2c-\sin c$$
$$\frac{x^2+\cos x-1}{x}=2c-\sin c$$
$-1\le\sin c\le1 \implies -1\le-\sin c\le1 \implies 2c-1\le 2c-\sin c\le 2c+1$
$$\frac{x^2+\cos x-1}{x}\ge 2c-1$$
And now i'm stuck because i can't get $x(2c-1)>0$

Is my proof wrong somewhere?

UPDATE: Thanks for everyone that gave their input. I managed to solve it using $f(x) = 1-\cos x$ directly. However, i'm still curious as to why my initial method fails? is there something that I overlooked?

Comment: You know that $f(0)=1$ so all you need to show is that $f'>0$

Comment: @David Oh sorry, there was an error in my expression, just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Why  not use the MVT on $1-\cos x$ directly? The derivative is $\sin x$ hence there exists $u$ in $(0,1)$ such that $1-\cos x=x\sin(ux)$ by the MVT. The MVT again shows that $\sin(ux)=\sin(ux)-0=ux\cos(uvx)$ for some $v$ in $(0,1)$. Now, $|\cos(uvx)|\leqslant1$ hence you are done.

Comment: Stronger inequality $1-\frac{x^2}{2}\le \cos(x)\le1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$ is shown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513020/prove-the-inequalities-1-fracx22-le-cosx-le1-fracx22-fracx4

Comment: What does the assertion "$x\gt0\implies(0,x)$" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bound is not good enough if you want to proceed this way. One fix is to use a better bound than $-1≤\sin c ≤ 1$. Your bound gives you $2c-\sin c>0$ if $c>1$. For $c≤1$, we know that $$\sin c - 0 = c \cos c'$$ for some $c' ∈ (0,c)$ by MVT. Also note that $|\cos c'|\leq 1$. Therefore $-\sin c ≥  -c$, so $2c - \sin c ≥ 2c - c = c > 0$, which proves the result.

In summary, we made the improved piecewise bound
$$ 2c- \sin c ≥ \begin{cases} 2c-1 & c>1 \\ c & 0<c<1 \end{cases} ≥ c > 0$$

In fact, we didnt even need that $c≤1$, just that $c>0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! Made things a lot clearer. Thanks man:)

Answer (score 2):

Easier:

Since
$\cos'(x)
=-\sin(x)
$,
$\cos(x)-\cos(0)
=-\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\ge -\int_0^x t dt
=-\frac{x^2}{2}
$
so
$1-\cos(x)
\le \frac{x^2}{2}
< x^2
$
for
$x \ne 0$.

To show that
$\sin(x) \le x$,
start with
$\sin'(x)
= \cos(x)
$.
then
$\sin(x)
=\sin(x)-\sin(0)
=\int_0^x \cos(t) dt
\le\int_0^x  dt
=x
$
since
$\cos(t) \le 1$.

Comment: just curious, does your proof for $\sin x\le x$ work for $|\sin x|<|x|$?